# Doubt in derivative computation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, intuition, actuarial-science

I quote *Life Insurance Mathematics (Gerber, 1997)*.

---

Let us consider a person aged $x$ years, denoted by $(x)$. We denote his/her future lifetime by $T$ or, more explicitly, by $T(x)$. Thus $x+T$ will be the age at death of the person.

The future lifetime $T$ is a random variable with a probability distribution function
\begin{equation}
G(t)=\mathbb{P}\left(T\leq t\right)\text{, }t\geq0\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Define $_t p_x$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
_t p_x=1-G(t)=\mathbb{P}\left(T>t\right)\text{, }t\geq0\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Define $\mu_{x+t}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
\mu_{x+t}=-\frac{d}{dt}\ln\hspace{0,1cm} _{t}p_{x}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

---

---

For $0<u<1$, let us assume that $\mu_{x+u}$ is a constant. Let us denote the constant value of $\mu_{x+u}$ by $\mu_{x+\frac{1}{2}}$.

$\color{red}{\text{Using }(3)\text{ one finds:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{\mu_{x+\frac{1}{2}}=-\ln p_x\tag{4}}
\end{equation}

---

---

---

I cannot really understand why applying $(3)$, one would get $(4)$ for $t=\frac{1}{2}$. Could you please help me understand that?

Comment: What is the definition of $p_x$?

Comment: Generally, by convention, $p_x= _{1}p_x$. Hence, by $(2)$ I guess that $p_x=\mathbb{P}\left(T>1\right)$ @LouisPan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what was meant to be understood by "assume that $\mu_{x+u}$ is a constant."
I will suppose it means that for $0 < t < 1$ and a fixed $x$ we are to assume that $\ln {}_tp_x$ has a constant derivative with respect to $t$.
(This is the application of Equation $(3)$.)

We then find that $\ln {}_tp_x = at + b$, that is, ${}_tp_x = e^{at + b},$ for some constants $a$ and $b$, provided that $0 < t < 1.$
If we also make the reasonable assumption (perhaps already implied in the textbook) that ${}_tp_x = \mathbb P(T>t)$ is a continuous function of $t,$
we find that ${}_0p_x = \lim_{t\to 0} e^{at + b} = e^b$
and ${}_1p_x = \lim_{t\to 1} e^{at + b} = e^{a+b}.$

Presumably $\mathbb P(T>0) = 1$, so
$$
e^b = {}_0p_x = \mathbb P(T>0) = 1,
$$
which implies $b = 0,$ so $\ln {}_tp_x = at,$
and in particular $\ln {}_1p_x = a.$
Then (for $0 < t < 1$)
$$
\mu_{x+t} = -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\ln {}_tp_x
= -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}at = -a = -\ln {}_1p_x.
$$

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. Could you please help me understand why one can supposte the "exponential form" of $_0 p_x$, that is why one can suppose that $e^b= {}_0 p_x$? And why does such a passage "serve" so as to explain the result?

Comment: I implicitly made a continuity assumption; now I've made it explicit. I'm not sure what you mean by "explain" the result: do you mean an *intuitive* explanation as opposed to formal derivation?

Comment: Yes, of course, I was meaning an *intuitive* explanation as opposed to formal derivation. Thank you a lot for the very clear edit as it concerns my previous question

Comment: The most intuitive concept I have at this time is that $\ln {}_tp_x$ has to start at $0$ (since $P(T>t)$ starts at $1$) and since we assume a uniform rate of change for $\ln {}_tp_x$ between $t=0$ and $t=1$, the value it reaches after one unit of time is just equal to that rate of change. That's kind of just a less rigorous restatement of the derivation, however.

Comment: Extremely clear, thank you a lot again :)